# Net speed, sticky-Notes started hiding after installing Tweaks on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, system-monitor, gnome-tweak-tool, stickynotes

After wake-up from suspend or whenever restart my system
[image: After wake-up from suspend or whenever restart my system]

After apply <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and press Enter with 'r' in the text-box, I got my netspeed on panel, Each time I have to do the same to make these available  on panel
[image: After apply Alt+f2 and press Enter with 'r' in the text-box, I got my netspeed on panel, Each time I have to do the same to make these available on panel]